# Best database structure for ecommerce website

Tags: database, zend-framework

I want to know how do you programmer handle an ecommerce site like this one in Mysql http://shop.ccs.com with all the relative between product, quanlity of product, Size, color prices. mine is

1. table products

   1. id
   2. name
   3. parents
2. table size

   1. id
   2. id_product
   3. size_name
   4. quantity
3. table color

   1. id
   2. id_product
   3. colors
   4. quantity

Comment: u want a database model?

Comment: im pretty noob here so, maybe it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm.. i came up with this structure, hope that will help a bit. One should have a Master Table with the product information. Here in ur case, its product id, size and color repec. and rest of the tables connects to the master table

```
1.table products_id (master table)
     1.id- Primary Key
     2.id_product_size- References size.id (FK)
     3.id_product_color- References color.id (FK)

 2. table product_name
     1.product_id- References product_id.id(FK)
     2.name
     3.parents

 3.table size 
     1.id- Primary Key
     2.size_name
     3.quantity

 4.table color 
     1.id- Primary Key
     2.colors
     3.quantity
```

Comment: And what about category of products for example shoes, or t-shirt in that case the table must add id_product_category into products_id master table, is that right?